# Pyspark group rows with sequential numbers ( with duplicates)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have data which has a sequential time slot of customers arrivals

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, 'A'),
     (1, 'B'),
     (1, 'C'),
     (5, 'D'),
     (8, 'A'),
     (9, 'F'),
     (20, 'T'),
     (20, 'S'),
     (21, 'C')],
    ['time_slot', 'customer'])
```

```
+--------+--------+
|time_slot|customer|
+--------+--------+
|       0|       A|
|       1|       B|
|       1|       C|
|       5|       D|
|       8|       A|
|       9|       F|
|      20|       T|
|      20|       S|
|      21|       C|
+--------+--------+
```

I need to group customers by the sequential time slots (including duplicates), so that I can get:

```
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|       grouped_slots|                            grouped_customers|
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|              [0, 1]|                              ['A', 'B', 'C']|
|                 [5]|                                        ['D']|
|              [8, 9]|                                   ['A', 'F']|
|            [20, 21]|                              ['T', 'S', 'C']|
+--------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

I have tried to use the lag function to look at the prev record but not sure how to group based on that

```py
window = W.orderBy("time_slot")
df = df.withColumn("prev_time_slot", F.lag(F.col('time_slot'), 1).over(window))
```

```
+---------+--------+--------------+
|time_slot|customer|prev_time_slot|
+---------+--------+--------------+
|        0|       A|          null|
|        1|       B|             0|
|        1|       C|             1|
|        5|       D|             1|
|        8|       A|             5|
|        9|       F|             8|
|       20|       T|             9|
|       20|       S|            20|
|       21|       C|            20|
+---------+--------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, yes it seems a bit similar to the first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code first computes a lag column containing the previous row's time slot. Then, it marks the start of a new sequence whenever the difference between the current time slot and the previous one is more than 1. It uses a cumulative sum to create a unique group ID for each sequence. Lastly, it groups the DataFrame by these group IDs, aggregating the time slots and customers into lists:

```
window = Window.orderBy("time_slot")


df = df.withColumn("prev_time_slot", F.lag(F.col('time_slot')).over(window))


df = df.withColumn("isNewSequence", 
                   (F.col("time_slot") - F.col("prev_time_slot") > 1).cast("int"))


df = df.withColumn("groupId", F.sum("isNewSequence").over(window))


df_grouped = df.groupBy("groupId").agg(F.collect_set("time_slot").alias("grouped_slots"), 
                                        F.collect_set("customer").alias("grouped_customers"))

df_grouped.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thanks so much it works, just had to change `collect_list` to `collect_set`